# JavaScript .map() to update array with value from another array - returns value but key is undefined

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have two arrays.

I want to update `array1` by getting `array2` `multiple` value by matching on each array's `color` value.

I am using this to do the following code to do the work. Note for purposes of this question both array contents are fake data not my actual array data.

```js
const array1 = [{color: "blue", report_date: "2020-12-12", count: "10"},
          {color: "blue", report_date: "2020-12-13", count: "20"},
          {color: "red", report_date: "2020-12-14", count: "4"}]

const array2 = [{color: "blue", multiple: ".2"},
          {color: "red", multiple: ".3"}]


const array3 = array1.map(t1 => ({...t1, ...array2.find(t2 => t2.color === t1.color)}))

console.log(array3);
```

The code does return expected results here.

However, when I use my actual arrays, it does correctly return *multiple* values, but it shows *color* as undefined eg as follows:

```
array3 = [{color: undefined, report_date: "2020-12-12", count: "10", multiple: ".2"},
          {color: undefined, report_date: "2020-12-13", count: "20", multiple: ".2"},
          {color: undefined, report_date: "2020-12-14", count: "4", multiple: ".3"}]
```

Can anyone provide any troubleshooting hints as to why I see color = *undefined* for my actual arrays?

Comment: I converted your code to a runnable snippet but it doesn't reproduce the problem. Are you updating the `color` value later? See [Is Chrome's JavaScript console lazy about evaluating arrays?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4057440)

Comment: It's giving correct results only right

Comment: yeah for me too .. its showing me correct result

Comment: Hmm yes it works here indeed. Although I created these generalized arrays for purpose of this question, they are not my actual arrays which give me these results. But I cannot see any meaningful difference in them.

Comment: @curtisp then read the link I posted. It's possible that the property is changed *later*. Since the console evaluates objects lazily, it will show you the *current* state of the data in them, not the data at the time of logging. So, if it was updated after the merging, you'd see that reflected.

Comment: Thanks. Note that I did copy and run code with fake arrays locally (Chrome) and it returns expected results eg shows `color` value (is not undefined). So it is something with my actual arrays causing problem. But they look just like my generalized arrays in structure and format,  if not content.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to `JSON.stringify` the output in order to see that in fact the `color` values were correctly populated.

Eg this shows the `color` values as expected:

```
console.log(JSON.stringify(array3));
```

For some reason, just using:

```
console.log(array3);
```

Showed the `color` values as `undefined`.